# MediaPlayer doesn't work when it is not declared private

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

***Reposting question: As i didn't get an answer for 15 days and i don't have enough bounty to shelve off.***

I am a beginner to android programming and am trying to create an app which plays a certain sound.when the ListView item is clicked on, however when I declare the MediaPlayer object (as given below) inside the onItemClick method the app crashes.

```
  phrasesActivityListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Word currentWord = phrases.get(position);
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PhrasesActivity.this, currentWord.getAudioResourceId());
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

where the phrasesActivityListView is the name of the ListView

whereas when i declare a the MediaPlayer object as private the app works(as shown below )

```
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
.
.
 phrasesActivityListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Word currentWord = phrases.get(position);
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(PhrasesActivity.this, currentWord.getAudioResourceId());
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

why? And I have also included the Word Class below

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

public class Word {
//Default translation of the word
private String mDefaultTranslation;
//Miwok translation of the word
private String mMiwokTranslation;
//Resource id of the image to be shown on the screen.It is set to minus one so that it can be verified that whether the resource id is associated with any ImageView.
private int mImageResourceId = -1;
//Resource id of the audio file that is going to be played when the user click on the ListView item.
private int mAudioResourceId;

//Constructor to intialise the values of text in the textViewx
public Word(String defaultTranslation, String miwokTranslation, int audioResourceId) {
    mDefaultTranslation = defaultTranslation;
    mMiwokTranslation = miwokTranslation;
    mAudioResourceId = audioResourceId;
}

//Constructor to intialise the values of text and the resource for the TextView and the ImageView.
public Word(String defaultTranslation, String miwokTranslation, int imageResourceId, int audioResourceId) {
    mDefaultTranslation = defaultTranslation;
    mMiwokTranslation = miwokTranslation;
    mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    mImageResourceId = audioResourceId;
}

//Returns the defaultTranslation of the word
public String getDefaultTranslation() {
    return mDefaultTranslation;
}

//Returns the Miwok translation of the word.
public String getMiwokTranslation() {
    return mMiwokTranslation;
}

//Returns the image resource id of the image.
public int getImageResourceId() {
    return mImageResourceId;
}

//Checks whether the resource view has been intialised when creating a ImageView.
public boolean hasImage() {
    return mImageResourceId != -1;
}
//Returns the audio resource id of the audio.

public int getAudioResourceId() {
    return mAudioResourceId;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In your first code snippet, `mediaPlayer` is a local variable. It goes out of scope as soon as `onItemClick()` returns, and it will be eligible for garbage collection. Since you want that object to live for a bit longer than that, you need to hold onto it somewhere else, such as inside the activity or fragment in which this code resides.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are preserving the object of Your list view `phrasesActivityListView`, in the same way You need to declare Your media player object. So that it can live longer to play whatever You wants to play.
More You should read the [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) of media player also. It will make clear how You should deal with media player object like release the object, sequence of prepare and start.